# Как работает поиск репозитариев по критериям: Readme, Description, Name?

Tags: c#, github, octokit.net, github-api

Пробую сделать api для github на базе octokit.net ([ссылка](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net))

Вопрос по поиску по репозитариям.
Поисковая фраза - api for github;
Количество результатов поиска определяю - result.TotalCount

Таблица результатов поиска ([ссылка](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15AVEg9ZFli-u6TdDqRPUol6PfruwI9xt8qH0YagarM8/edit?usp=sharing))
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос.**
1. По какому варианту выполняет поиск "octokit.net"?

Вариант 1 - использует оператор "AND"?
In = new[] {
InQualifier.Readme,
and
InQualifier.Description,
and
InQualifier.Name
}

Вариант 2 - использует оператор "OR"?
In = new[] {
InQualifier.Readme,
or
InQualifier.Description,
or
InQualifier.Name
}

Или есть другие способы?

2. Как поиск "octokit.net" использует слова поиска:

   - "api for github" - иищет фразу целиком?
   - "api" AND "for" AND "github" - использует оператор "AND"?
   - "api" OR "for" OR "github" - использует оператор "OR"?
3. Как выполняет поиск "github.com"?
   Предположу: если результат "№1" из таблицы приблизительно равен "№4", то "github.com" ищет репозитарии по описанию.
   Правильно ли я понял?

Comment: Кто такой октокитнет и почему мы должны знать, как у него устроен поиск?

Comment: обычно поиск устроен гораздо сложнее, чем AND/OR... сортировка по релевантности. Все три слова - максимальная релевантность, два из трех поменьше...

Comment: @vp_arth `>Кто такой октокитнет и почему мы должны знать, как у него устроен поиск?` -  В начале вопроса указал ссылку... Или вообще вопрос не по адресу? Я просто думал, может кто использовал...